# Is the 'category' identifier now mandatory in the APNS payload?

Tags: push-notification, ios8, apple-push-notifications

In WWDC 2014 "What's New in iOS notifications" session, it is explained that when you implement custom actions for push notifications, you have to put them into categories. However, in my app I do not want to use this feature yet. This is the code I'm using for registering for push notifications. Notice that I use `nil` as the categories parameter.

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
```

Do I have to set the `category` key into my APNS payload? If so, which category should I pick? Do I have to create a default one?